# How can I transfer data(directions) from Google Map and pass it to my app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am doing this for my senior design project. I am using Java on Android. I already created my own android application with BlueTooth send/recieve command. Now, what I need to do is try to get direction/distance from **Google Map into my app** after I put in some address on my app and go to navigation mode in Google Map app.

For example, If the destination is 100/50/25 ft up ahead, I want my app to know that the destination is 100/50/25 ft away and send different commands to microprocessor. If I need to turn right in 100 ft, my app will send another command. If I have to make a u-turn, my app will send some another command.

I already implemented my app, now all is need is Google Map data to use in my algorithm which will be send a command to microprocesor. Sorry if I made this question confusing. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Google Maps Android API and see if you can pull the information you want from that. If i understand your question correctly (based on this quote "after I put in some address on my app and go to navigation mode in Google Map app."), you could also use this API to call the navigation function and have that launch google maps to navigate you.

Take a look:

Directions API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro 
Android API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/